# How to calculate the age

Tags: date-and-time

How to calculate my age given date of birth? I have read other questions and answers but is not satisfied with answers. My question is how do I calculate my age if my date of birth is 18.03.2000?

Answer (score 1):

```
dob = "18.03.2000";

age = DateDifference[DateList[{dob, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], DateList[], "Year"]
```

> 18.8148 yr

Answer (score 1):

```
DateDifference[{2000, 3, 18}, Date[], "Year"]

18.814yr
```